# Conditonally check if Custom Meta Box has input

Tags: metabox

I currently display a URL from a custom meta box, but wanted to add a conditional check, so that if nothing has been entered, not to display the link text.

```
<a target="_blank" href="<?php $urlbox = get_url_desc_box(); echo $urlbox[0]; ?>">Visit Website &raquo;</a>
```

At the moment, even when nothing is added to the URL Meta BOX, the *Visit Website* text still appears within the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$urlbox = get_url_desc_box();

if ( !empty( $urlbox[0] ) ) {
    echo sprintf( '<a target="_blank" href="%s">Visit Website &raquo;</a>', $urlbox[0] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just need to move your logic outside of the `<a>` tag, and create a condition to only display if the result isn't null

```
<?php 
$urlbox = get_url_desc_box();
if ($urlbox[0] != null) { ?>
      <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $urlbox[0]; ?>">Visit Website &raquo;</a>
<?php } ?>
```